# capistrano halted at bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

Just come across an issue with capistrano recipe. I tried to deploy a Rails 3.2 app to a Solaris server. Everything runs okay until `bundle install`. It throws this error `/opt/rubyenterprise/lib/gems/bin/bundle:9:in`require':no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)`. I added these into config file:

```
set :default_environment, {
'PATH' => [Full path on server],
'GEM_HOME' => '/opt/rubyenterprise/lib/gems',
'GEM_PATH' => '/opt/rubyenterprise/lib/gems/gems'
}
```

Im pretty sure I got $PATH, $GEM_HOME and $GEM_PATH correctly. Tried again but error still occurs. Has anyone had this issue before and how did you resolve it?Server is running REE 1.8.7 only.